# How can I copy contents of one directory to another with the AWS api?

Tags: c#, amazon-s3

- bucketName/folder1/image.jpg
- bucketName/folder1/someDoc.doc
- bucketName/folder1/somePdf.pdf
- bucketName/folder2/someOtherImage.jpeg

I want to be able to copy all the contents of folder1 to folder2 and remove it from folder 1.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the S3DirectoryInfo class using AWSSDK(3.x.x version) C#.
this class has  MoveTo method see the code below.

```
        public static void MoveFiles()
        {
            BasicAWSCredentials basicCredentials = new BasicAWSCredentials("access key", "secret key");
            AmazonS3Config configurationClient = new AmazonS3Config();
            configurationClient.RegionEndpoint = RegionEndpoint.EUCentral1;//region of bucket
            try
            {
                using (AmazonS3Client clientConnection = new AmazonS3Client(basicCredentials, configurationClient))
                {
                    S3DirectoryInfo source = new S3DirectoryInfo(clientConnection, "sourcebucketname", "sourcefolderkey");
                    S3DirectoryInfo target = new S3DirectoryInfo(clientConnection, "destinationbucketname", "destinationfolderkey");
                    source.MoveTo(target);// move all  content from FolderNameUniTest109 to FolderNameUniTest179

                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {

            }



        }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
PutObjectRequest request = new PutObjectRequest();
            request.WithBucketName(BUCKET_NAME);
            request.WithKey(PrefixFolder + folderPath[i] + addProjectResponse.ProjectName.Replace("_", " ") + "/");
            request.WithTimeout(-1);
            request.WithReadWriteTimeout(60 * 60 * 1000);
            request.WithContentBody("");
            s3Client.PutObject(request);
            S3DirectoryInfo source = new S3DirectoryInfo(s3Client, BUCKET_NAME, PrefixFolder + folderPath[i] + addProjectResponse.OldProjectName.Replace("_", " "));
            S3DirectoryInfo destination = new S3DirectoryInfo(s3Client, BUCKET_NAME, PrefixFolder + folderPath[i] + addProjectResponse.ProjectName.Replace("_", " "));
            source.CopyTo(destination);

            source.Delete(true);
```

Here once you copied from one to another first folder is getting deleted.